# Cryptsy, Mintpal, Bittrex API - how many requests can I do?

Tags: api, cryptsy, bittrex, mintpal

Cryptsy, Mintpal and Bittrex have public APIs.

How many requests per second or minute can I do to these APIs?

Comment: There's still no information about Cryptsy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mintpal has a limit of [10 requests/second](https://www.mintpal.com/api/v1)

> MintPal API v1 offers a simple REST API to retrieve information about our markets. The API responses are JSON encoded arrays. **Please be aware that calls to the API are rate limited to 10 requests per second**, any requests exceeding this rate will be met with a HTTP 503 response.

I know Kraken has different rules. You can 'burst', instead of a flat limit. [Source](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=290799.msg3444767#msg3444767)

> The basic API rate limit is **1 call every 5 seconds**. You can do faster bursts up to 10 calls, but then you'd need to follow that by a 50 second pause before you could resume the 1 call very 5 second rate. If you get locked out, it's for 15 minutes.
>
> For really active traders (including those who want to market make with us), we can offer much higher limits. Anyone interested in this should contact us with a support ticket.

I know Kraken isn't on your wishlist of things to know, but I cannot find information about Cryptsy or Bittrex. But it gives you a insight at real limits, so you can maybe assume those two have similar limits.

Answer (score 0):

For Bittrex, [this post](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/59316/trading-bot-what-is-the-maximum-load-an-exchange-server-can-take) mentions they got banned for a week for spamming the API. The email they received from Bittrex lifting the ban said to limit to 1 request per second.

Unfortunately, there is still nothing on their official documentation, and I've found their support to be slow-never to respond.

So we're stuck with hearsay for now.